# Convert Raw JSON Text from getting the URL and make it an IMAGE

Tags: php, json, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

I am trying to connect to the external site and get the products there and copy them to another site by using its consumer and `secret keys`.

I have the a URL Link that links from an External Site[1](https://samplelink.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=sample-consumer_key&consumer_secret=sample_consumer_secret).
Now I get all the `JSON` Data (including sales, images, data etc.) by using `PHP` CURL

Here is the code:

```
function get_wc_api_client() {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $site = 'https://samplelink.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=sample-consumer_key&consumer_secret=sample_consumer_secret';
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $site );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(    json_decode($content, true)) ;
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Any recommendations how to just get the IMAGES and the TITLE of the PRODUCT of the external site, plus the links of each products and display them as a full images and text not JSON text ?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATES:**
Here is the example code of the Result for the print_r

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4591
            [name] => Magic Forest
            [slug] => magic-forest
            [permalink] => https://samplesite.com/product/magic-forest/
            [date_created] => 2019-03-13T19:11:09
            [date_created_gmt] => 2019-03-13T19:11:09
            [date_modified] => 2019-03-13T19:12:20
            [date_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-13T19:12:20
            [type] => simple
            [status] => publish
            [featured] => 
            [catalog_visibility] => visible
            [description] =>
```

but as I said, I only need the IMAGE, TITLE of the Products and their links and VIEW them as real IMAGE and TITLE and Link.

```
[images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4932
                            [date_created] => 2019-03-13T18:54:54
                            [date_created_gmt] => 2019-03-13T18:54:54
                            [date_modified] => 2019-03-13T18:55:14
                            [date_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-13T18:55:14
                            [src] => https://samplesite.com/wpcom-129014632/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Pond-image.jpg
                            [name] => Pond Cover
                            [alt] => 
                            [position] => 0
                        )
```

FOR IMAGE: I needed the image src link to be a Real image when executed, also the title of the product.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please show the result of print_r(json_decode($content, true)); ?

Comment: updated my post above

Comment: where is image path?

Comment: update again the post above

Comment: what do you want to do with the image, title, and product? you want to save the image? or save it to variable/database? or something else?

Comment: @askCocoa do you want result like echo '<image src="'.$data['src'].'" title="'.$data['name'].'" alt="'.$data['alt'].'">'?

Comment: yes, you are right got it by    
echo "<img class='product-images-shop' src='" .$value["images"][0]['src']."'>";

thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
 function get_wc_api_client() {
   $curl = curl_init();
   $site = 'https://samplelink.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=sample-consumer_key&consumer_secret=sample_consumer_secret';
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $site );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
   $content = curl_exec($curl);
   return json_decode($content, true);
 }
```

Call this function in your view page

```
   $apiData = get_wc_api_client();

  foreach($apiData['images'] as $data){
     echo '<image src="'.$data['src'].'" title="'.$data['name'].'" alt="'.$data['alt'].'">';
  }
```